# Strange loop when using DigestInputStream in Java

Tags: java, hash

The following code supposed to compute the hash for a string in a text file using `DigestInputStream` class in Java.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.*;

public class ReturnDigest extends Thread {

     private File input;
     private byte[] digest;

    public ReturnDigest(File input) {
     this.input = input;
    }

        public void run() {
          try {
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(input);
        MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
        DigestInputStream din = new DigestInputStream(in, sha);
        int b;
        while ((b = din.read()) != -1) ;
        din.close();
        digest = sha.digest();
      }
          catch (IOException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }
          catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
        System.err.println(ex);
      }

    }

        public byte[] getDigest() {
      return digest;
    }

}
```

My question is: why there is a semicolon after the `while` statement? Is this correct? When I remove it, I get error. I have not ever heard that it is possible to put a semicolon after a while statement. Can you clarify the case in this code please.

Comment: It is an empty loop till `din.read() != -1` !!!To simply clear all data from the stream probably !

Comment: @AsierAranbarri: your answer is good (and I did upvote it), but maybe he was looking for some more information on why there's an empty loop (it's not too common after all).

Comment: @JoachimSauer I understand your answer is better. Gives him more information about the issue and it's clear you have more experience than me. I just put the comment (just deleted it) because he ticked my answer first, then unticked it, and later ticked yours. Something odd...I was just in a bad mood! : )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's an empty loop, nothing is done with the value read. In fact one could get rid of the variable `b` altogether:

```
while (din.read() != -1) {
}
```

I also replaced the semicolon (empty statement) with an empty block, as that's slightly more explicit about what happens here.

This is a very atypical way to read from an input stream (usually you want to *do* something with the data that was read), because the digest input stream has a side-effect: if you read from it it *also* computes the hash of whatever is read. If you *only* want the hash, you need to read, but don't need to do anything with the values that where read.

Comment: Make sure you are using `BufferedInputStream` around your `din` input stream, or your performance would suffer reading data byte by byte as opposed to reading it in chunks.

Answer (score 1):

It is correct.

```
while ((b = din.read()) != -1) ;
din.close();
```

The `While` loop will only exit when din.read() is not -1, when there's nothing more to read. Then and just then will close it.

So you can see it:

```
while ((b = din.read()) != -1) ;
```

and

```
while ((b = din.read()) != -1) 
{  }
```

Are equal.

Answer (score -1):

```
    MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
    DigestInputStream digestInputStream = new DigestInputStream(inputStream, messageDigest);
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
    int count = 0;
    while (digestInputStream.read(buffer) > -1) {
        count++;
    }
    log.info("total read: " + count);
    MessageDigest digest = digestInputStream.getMessageDigest();
    digestInputStream.close();
    byte[] md5 = digest.digest();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (byte b: md5) {
        sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
    }
    String checkSum = sb.toString();
```